# Loop in R while all the column values are true

Tags: r, loops, expression, grouping, summarize

I would like to make a loop to find only TRUE values. I have columns: name, parameter, value. I have 9 different values connected with one Name and different parameters connected with parameter column. First I need to group by name and parameter, find mean and sd and use the expression (it is imaginery expression below, maybe bot the correct one) to see is it meets the criteria (TRUE OR FALSE). Then I need to drop out all the FALSE values and do everything again (grouping by name and parameter, find mean and sd and use the expression) until there is no FALSE value in the column.

How I should do that?

It is something for doing it once:

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(name, parameter) %>%
  summarise_at(parameter, list(mean=mean, sd=sd), na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(result=sd - mean < mean - 1.5*sd & mean - sd < sd + 1.5*mean) %>% 
  drop_na()
```

But I need to do it again until all the results are always TRUE.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I would beware of recursive sieving datasets.  This often leads to removing stuff which is valid but you "don't like."

Comment: Anyway, the general answer is not to use `for` but rather  `while(something_is_FALSE)`

Comment: ^as an example of the pitfalls of this, if you ran this on `parameter = (5:100)^2` you'd start with 96 observations but after ~25 iterations you'd only be keeping 6, which is surely excessive.

Comment: I am still struggling with while as well. If I use this code without loop or something like that, then I have to run the same code 12 times (I copied 12 times the same code, where I changed df1...12 to get rid of all the FALSE values, but with another df it could be different.

`df2<-df1 %>%
  group_by(Name, Parameter) %>%
  summarise(x= x, mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)) %>% 
  mutate(result=sd - mean < mean - sd & mean - sd < sd + mean) %>% 
  filter (result == TRUE)`

I still don't know how to add while here.

Comment: With while, could it be something like that? But it still doesn't work: Error in while (d1$result == TRUE) { : the condition has length > 1

`while (d1$result == TRUE) {
  d2<-d1 %>%  group_by(Name, Parameter) %>%
  summarise(x= x, mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)) %>% 
  mutate(result=sd - mean < mean - sd & mean - sd < sd + mean)  
}`